# Unable to close AdMob interstitial ad

Tags: android, admob

Lately, my android app has been showing Admob interstitial ads that cannot be dismissed.  It seems the back button action to dismiss an ad was discontinued.  Most interstitial ads include a "Close" button on the ad itself, but not all of them do.  When an interstitial ad is delivered without a close button, the only way to close the ad is to kill the app.

Here is an example of an ad we received without a close button:

[image]

I am using 
`implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.0.0'`

in my Gradle build.

So the question is:  Is there any way to close an interstitial ad aside from pressing the close button on the ad?

Comment: I got same issue and it looks like the issue still not fixed yet. Did you resolve this issue?

Comment: I get the same issue with version 19.2.0 too. BTW we've got complaints about the very same ad (lots of them from "lendingtree") so we had to block them from AdMod dashboard. But recently our users started complaining again; one reason being their phone's default font size is bigger which causes "x" not be visible, plus the phone's back button is not closing the ad either (even after ~5 seconds). Any other insights?

Comment: Yes, we are seeing the same issue again in some of our apps.  We also have had to block certain advertisers which seems to be the only solution.  We are not doing anything unusual in onBackPressed or onKeyDown of the hosting activities.  I suggest you file a report as did we through the admob developers portal.

Comment: Getting the same issue here with version 19.3.0 . Some users from other countries are reporting that they can't close the ads, but I can't reproduce the problem here... Anyone solved the problem, or got any response from Admob about this?

Comment: We have reported the issue twice to admob but never heard back from them.  You can review ads that were delivered to your app through the admob site and block ads that do not have a close button, but that is a temporary and incomplete solution.   Google really needs to fix this.

Comment: My users can't close the ads and they must force close the app to use it. I'm getting negative reviews (a lot) because of this. My app is in landscape and I don't know what's going on. I could replicate the issue, I'm pressing the back button nothing happens, or the "X" close button is missing (sometimes the ad is only half visible (probably because of landscape?!)). What should I do?

Comment: I still couldn't reproduce the problem, but I received email from users with screenshots showing the problem, and I realized exactly the same thing that @ZbarceaChristian said, the ad appears only half on the screen, apparently it is loading an portrait ad but with the device in landscape, so the close button is not shown on the screen.

Comment: Apparently this problem only occurs in the versions of Android 8.0 and 8.1, because all the complaints that I received in the reviews the users had their devices in these versions.

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

If the interstitial should be cropped so that the close button does not appear, it may be due to the max_aspect setting in your AndroidManifest.

For Interstitial the android.resizeableActivity setting has to be true.

In may application I have set the android.resizeableActivity=true in the application tag
but set my android.max_aspect to 1.8 which is needed for my game.
And only in my main acticity tag i set the android:resizeableActivity="false"

```
<application
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:resizeableActivity="true"
   >

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="@string/admob_App_id" />

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
        android:value="@string/app_id" />

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <meta-data android:name="android.max_aspect" android:value="1.8" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.entwicklerx.macedefense.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:resizeableActivity="false">
```

I hope this helps someone who has stumbled into the same problem as I recently

Comment: That is a good thought, although it will not help if the ad is delivered without a close button.  Maybe admob's motivation is that they higher revenue by disabling the back button.  Sure would be nice to get a response from them when an issue is reported.

Answer (score 0):

It seem like AdMob did some A/B testing on Back button (back button closed the Ads for some users and did not do anything for other users) but now it seems that AdMob chose the later option (back button do nothing)

I noticed this with some Ads, most probably it is an AdMob bug related to certain Ads creative sizes on some phones.

Also I've noticed that it stopped happening using newer SDK versions.

Answer (score -2):

Interstitital ads can be closed by back button.

Remove all minterstitial.loadad code, and also showad code , which you call fram callback you implemented , like onadclose callback.

```
                 mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-........");
    // mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-......."); /// test ads

    MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {


            mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());


            mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener(){

                @Override
                public void onAdLoaded() {
                    super.onAdLoaded();

                    mInterstitialAd.show();

                }

                @Override
                public void onAdFailedToLoad(int i) {
                    super.onAdFailedToLoad(i);
                }

                @Override
                public void onAdClicked() {
                    super.onAdClicked();
                }

                @Override
                public void onAdLeftApplication() {
                    super.onAdLeftApplication();
                }

                @Override
                public void onAdOpened() {
                    super.onAdOpened();
                }
            });

        }
    });
```

Comment: As the question states, the back button has no effect.  Looking for some alternate way to close the ad which I can implement in the Activity's onBackPressed() or onKeyDown(int, KeyEvent)

Comment: There must be some event handler in your code , which you prevent the onBackPressed function correctly. My game app already disables back button , which user should not exit the multiplayer game by mistake. The interstitial ad already opens an other activity , which can be closed by back button, if some magical code does not prevent it from closing. Somewhere in your code possibly prevents it to behave normally.

Comment: I mean , in my app , although i prevent the user from using the back button to exit the app, i have no special code to close the ad . So , you do not need a closead function call, instead , remove what is preventing it.

Comment: We reported the bug to Admob.  Now everything is working again.  The back button now closes interstitials.

Comment: that's interesting. is it about encoding ? in which case does this happen ?

Comment: Could just be related to a bug in com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.0.0.  That's my best guess.  Anyhow, Interstitials are now behaving properly when the back button is pressed without any changes on our part.

Comment: in which version this bug is fixed ?

Comment: It is no longer fixed.  I am unable to do anything inside of onKeyDown or onBackPressed when an Interstitial ad is showing, so even if there was something like InterstitialAd.close() you wouldn't be able to call it when the user hits the back button.